# Prove or disprove: $Z_{25}$ is isomorphic to $R = Z_{5}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove or disprove:
$Z_{25}$ is isomorphic to $R = Z_{5}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$.

I tried to use the isomorphism theorems to show the two above are isomorphic, But i could not find homomorphism as required.

I belive this statement is false but I can't disprove it.
I know $Z_{25}$ is cyclic, But could not show R is not.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: What is $Z_{25}$? Integers modulo 25 ? In that case, there is no isomorphism. What is the (additive) order of $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Think about the additive order of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  Check if your quadratic is irreducible.   Here it's as simple as plugging in the numbers 0 through 4.

If you mod a ring out by an irreducible polynomial, you get a field.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_5$ as it has no root in $\Bbb Z_5$.
So the quotient ring is a field with 25 elements, written as $GF(25)$ (Galois Field), but its not isomorphic to the ring $\Bbb Z_{25}$.